# Taurus PassFail Issues when testing Jmeter.jmx script

Tags: linux, jmeter, taurus

So I'm learning a little bit about Taurus and was trying to apply some pass fail criteria to my .jmx script. When I try to evaluate a specific sampler, it seems to not run the pass fail criteria at all, but if I were to do a simple `avg-rt > 10s, continue as failed` , this works, but the issue is I want to evaluate each sampler specifically.

Here is a screenshot of my .yml file
[image]

I was using this link as reference to follow but I can't seem to get it to work with my script.
https://dzone.com/articles/running-your-load-tests-with-pass-fail-criteria-a

Any help and advice would be appreciated :)
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For me it seems to run pass/fail criteria

[image]

As you like screenshots here is the screenshot of [Taurus YAML](https://gettaurus.org/docs/YAMLTutorial/) file:

[image]

And here is the screenshot of "test.jmx" which basically uses simple single [Dummy Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-dummy-sampler-the-ultimate-guide/):

[image]

Just in case here is the link to the official documentation of the subsystem: [Pass/Fail Criteria](https://gettaurus.org/docs/PassFail/)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, I still can't seem to get it to work with my .jmx but I'll try recreating what you did! I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was that spaces matter lol.

rewriting it as `avg-rt of first_navigate>1s, continue as failed` does the trick :)